# WordPress question mark displayed for russian

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display the posts.

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l5di.png)

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Looks like the font that you are using isn't capable of displaying the Russian alphabet.

Comment: You have the wrong encoding to.use russian characters

Comment: This link is probably useful for you to resolve the issue yourself, this question is likely to get closed... [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. @naththedeveloper your link was useful. Found the issue. I was using `strtolower` in my code. Now I have changed it to `mb_strtolower(get_the_title($the_query->ID)`. Now it works.